# Required field display error message on form

Tags: php, forms, submit, required

I have a form that I need to have required fields filled out.  I know to use the code below to verify if the field is blank:

```
<?php
if  (!empty($_POST['client_name'])) {
echo '<p style="color:red;">'"Client Name is required!"'</p>';
}
?>
```

My question is, how do I get the error message to display on the form page, saving all the data already entered in the form.  Example: I fill out all 15 fields on the form, excluding the required field.  When I hit the submit button, if the required field is empty, I want to stay on that form page, without losing any of the info I put into the fields, and I want to display a message next to the required field box, saying "This is a required field.

I am not sure on the code to do that, or where to put it.  On the form, or on the script that executes the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use client side javascript validation first, then php server side validation.

Comment: here is a link to a good tutorial on how to setup the js http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 1):

Why you use !empty you can use empty for best result like

```
<?php
if  (empty($_POST['client_name'])) {
echo '<p style="color:red;">'"Client Name is required!"'</p>';
}
?>
```

Actually you should be first set HTML5 validation like

```
<input type="text" name="abc" required="">
```

You can set custom error message for required field like

```
<input type="text" name="abc" required="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Select This')">
```

Then you can use JS or jQuery validation and then user Server side Validation like PHP or ASP or others.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of your pages, it's hard to give an exact answer, but here's a general process flow that should help:

- Form is submitted to processor
- Processor validates inputs
- if inputs are good, processor redirects to next page
- if inputs are not good, processor should send error text and form data back to the routine that builds/displays the form.

IMHO, the processor should not `echo` anything. All display should be handled by the script that builds the form.

Without coding it for you, that's the best answer I can give :-)